# Accessing selection clipboard from ipython

Tags: python, clipboard, ipython

I want to access the text in the clipboard from within ipython.

I got this far (not even sure if this is the best way, just found by poking around in ipython magics sources):

```
import IPython
from IPython.core.hooks import clipboard_get
ip = IPython.get_ipython()
my_string = clipboard_get(ip)
```

And it kinda works for stuff I've copied manually, but I want to get the "other" clipboard - the one you get when you use the middle mouse click.  The selection buffer or whatever it's called.

Any ideas?

Comment: I don't think you can do this with `ipython` magics.  Looking at the docs, the clipboard api is just a wrapper around using `tkinter`'s clipboard handler, which (I don't believe) supports x buffers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get X Window's "middle mouse button" selection (called the `PRIMARY` selection) through Tkinter:

```
import Tkinter # Replace "Tkinter" with "tkinter" for Python 3.x.
tk = Tkinter.Tk()
tk.withdraw()
print(tk.selection_get())
```

Another solution is to run `xclip` and get its output. (If you don't have `xclip` installed it can be found in most Linux distributions' package repositories.)

```
import subprocess

print(subprocess.check_output(['xclip', '-o', '-selection', 'PRIMARY']))
```

Comment: Yeah, I thought of this too, maybe it is the best way.  No need to reinvent the wheel I guess.